# Aiogram bot . Quiz

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, asyncio, python-telegram-bot

пишу бота для телеграм . Возникла проблема с обработкой опросника

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['test'])       # обработка команды1
async def process_command_1(message: types.Message):
    quiz = get_quiz(1)
    for question in quiz:
        correct_option_id = get_question_correct_answer(question['options'])
        options = [option['text'] for option in question['options']]
        await bot.send_poll(chat_id=message.chat.id, question=question['task_text'], type='quiz', is_anonymous=False, cprrect_option_id=correct_option_id, options=options)
        await sleep(10)
```

Хочу, чтобы

**когда пользователь ответил на тест, сразу же выкидывался следующий вопрос,** на данный момент реализовано с помощью функции sleep(). Помогите , пожалуйста, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Мне кажется лучше использовать FSM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете сначала просто отправить викторину и записать её в переменную

```
my_quiz = await bot.send_poll(message.chat.id, 'Мессенджер, автор которого Павел Дуров', ['Telegram', 'Viber', 'WhatsApp', 'Messenger'], type='quiz', correct_option_id=0, is_anonymous=False)
```

(И обязательно, ещё раз - **ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО** не забудьте указать параметр `is_anonymous=False`)

Потом  сделать хэндлер получения ответа

```
@dp.poll_answer_handler()
async def handle_poll_answer(quiz_answer: PollAnswer):
    # проверяем ответ
    if my_quiz.poll.correct_option_id == quiz_answer.option_ids[0]:
        await bot.send_message(quiz_answer.user.id, 'Правильно! Идём дальше')
    else:
        await bot.sned_message(quiz_answer.user.id, 'Жаль, но это неправильный ответ. Двигаемся дальше - может потом повезёт')

    # отправляем следующую викторину
    await bot.send_poll(message.chat.id, 'Мессенджер, автор которого Павел Дуров', ['Telegram', 'Viber', 'WhatsApp', 'Messenger'], type='quiz', correct_option_id=0, is_anonymous=False)
```

И тогда новая викторина будет отправляться сразу после получения ответа на предыдущую

И ещё, убедительная просьба: Не отправляйте код скриншотом. Всем будет легче, если вы его просто скопируете, а для вас это на пару кликов больше

Comment: А откуда вы взяли из json-объекта `quiz_answer`  ключ `poll`, чтоб сравнить результат с `options_ids`?

Comment: Извиняюсь, там должна быть ваша викторина. Сейчас подправлю

Answer (score 0):

Делал подобное, но на `pytelegrambotapi`, думаю проблем не возникнет переписать на `aiogram`. При этом не обязательно использовать задержку.

Если вам **нужно именно** отслеживать количество верных ответов, то сделайте такую логику - первая функция `pre_poll` вызывает первую викторину, в ней обновляются данные в базе (в основном чтобы обнулить счетчики), при этом нужно записать куда-то верный ответ викторины, чтоб потом можно было сверить с выбором во второй функции с ответом юзера и уже инкрементировать по надобности счетчик. Так должно будет происходить до тех пор, пока не инкрементируется счетчик отправленных викторин, к примеру до 5 (не забывайте учитывать счетчик от 1, а не 0, так как первую викторину мы отправляем в функции `pre_poll`)

Пример ниже:

```
import random

# как только нужно отправить юзеру викторину - обращаемся к функции `pre_poll`
...
def pre_poll(message):
    # подключение к бд, обнуление счетчиков и выбор ответов
    # предположим, что res[0] - это вопрос, res[1] - верный ответ
    # все остальные ответы - неверные
    # также записываем верный ответ для последующей проверки
    # к примеру это будет записано в переменную ans
    data = [res[1], res[2], res[3], res[4]]
    random.shuffle(data)
    return bot.send_poll(chat_id=message.chat.id, question=res[0],
                         is_anonymous=False, options=data, type="quiz",
                         correct_option_id=data.index(res[1]))


# этот хендлер будет срабатывать каждый раз, когда юзер делает выбор в викторине
@bot.poll_answer_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def my_poll(message):
    # подключение к бд
    # предположим, что res[0] - это вопрос, res[1] - верный ответ
    # все остальные ответы - неверные 
    data = [res[1], res[2], res[3], res[4]]
    random.shuffle(data)
    if [ans] == message.options_ids:
        # если ответ, который мы записали совпадает с тем, который выбрал юзер
        # тогда инкрементируем счетчик на +1
        correct_count += 1
    # инкрементируем счетчик отправленных викторин
    # если счетчик не равен 5, тогда отправляем следующую викторину
    if count != 5:
        # перезаписываем верный ответ для следующей проверки викторины
        bot.send_poll(chat_id=message.user.id, question=res[0],
                      is_anonymous=False, options=data, type="quiz",
                      correct_option_id=data.index(res[1]))
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.user.id, 
                 f'Тестирование завершено.\nВерных ответов {correct_count} из 5.')
```